# How did the media know the name of the robot?

Tags: plot-explanation, chappie

I watched *Chappie* yesterday and had the following question:

TV News showed a footage of Chappie aiding criminals. Then they urged viewers to call authorities in case they see Chappie in their vicinity.

How did the media (News Stations) know the name of the robot?

Answer (score 3):

About one hour through the movie, the gang tricks Chappie into stealing a car (they tell him that the other guy stole daddy's car), Chappie destroys the car and throws away the other guy. At this point the gang calls Chappie back using his name, maybe that's how the media knows the name: the guy told them...

...or maybe it is just bad scripting...

Comment: no bad scripting, the movie is awesome